# How to increase speed of passing velocity commands to p3dx

Tags: ros, navigation, velocity, p3dx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am working on a project that requires me to send velocity commands to p3dx robot at a high speed. At the moment the robot takes a while (about 0.2s-0.3s) to change to a new speed once the command is given. Could you suggest any way in which I can increase this speed.
I am using "ROSARIA" to connect to the robot and subscribing via "cmd_vel". The robot is connected to the PC using an USB to RS422 converter.
Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/181941/how-to-increase-speed-of-passing-velocity-commands-to-p3dx/) by [Ashesh Goswami](https://answers.ros.org/users/8051/ashesh-goswami/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings! Perhaps try the [p2os](http://wiki.ros.org/p2os-vanderbilt) driver. Debians are available up to and including indigo. It's the same topic, so I don't think you'll need to modify your code. The p2os driver is a direct interface to the board, so the velocity commands will likely work with less latency.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ashesh Goswami](https://answers.ros.org/users/8051/ashesh-goswami/) on 2014-07-18**:
Thanks a lot. But I just wanted to clarify whether the p2os driver is applicable only when we are running the robot through onboard computer or can it still be used in case of serial communication with the robot say, using my PC?